# ImportError: cannot import name unwrap

Tags: python, scrapy, importerror

I have installed scrapy with `pip install scrapy`. But in python shell I am getting an ImportError:

```
>>> from scrapy.spider import Spider
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spider.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request import Request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.url import escape_ajax
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/url.py", line 10, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2, json
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 112, in <module>
    from urllib import (unwrap, unquote, splittype, splithost, quote,
ImportError: cannot import name unwrap
```

Also for scrapy shell, I am getting the same error. So I uninstalled scrapy with autoremove and installed it again but no change. Am I missing out on something?

Comment: Works for me (tm). Try doing a fresh install in a virtualenv? PS: Don't shadow the stdlib or builtins :)

Comment: I had another module named urllib.py so renamed it and now i am getting new error from scrapy import log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from scrapy.spider import Spider
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spider.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scrapy import log
ImportError: cannot import name log
 I checked the log.py does exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like that you've defined a module called `urllib.py` which **shadows built-in `urllib` module**. Remove/rename the file.

Comment: Haha didn't spot that there at first :)

Comment: Thanks that worked but now I am getting ImportError: cannot import log error