# ImportError : cannot import name unwrap

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have been trying to run my codes :
(neaweather.py)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

r = requests.get('http://www.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?   
dataset=2hr_nowcast&keyref=<keyrefno>')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
soup.find('validTime').string
```

However, when I run the codes, this is the error I got :

[Error on CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7usq.png)

I used to have a file called "urllib.py" (located on **C:\scripts** along with the file which im running neaweather.py) which clashes with the python modules however I have deleted the file. I have also deleted the file "urllib.pyc" from C:\scripts as well.

I have also deleted files for python3 which I have installed previously as im using python 2.7.12

I tried googling about this error and I saw a comment saying that .pyc files has something to do with this error. Is this true as I have already deleted the file "urllib.pyc" on C:\scripts

I'm not sure on how to solve this error, anyone?

This is not a duplicate of another similar error as I donot have a file name that clashes with python built in modules anymore as I have deleted it.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name unwrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077534/importerror-cannot-import-name-unwrap)

Comment: checkout this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077534/importerror-cannot-import-name-unwrap

Comment: @cyclops. The link isn't the same error he has encountered. In the traceback msg, it shows python interpreter has found the correct urllib which locates in "C:\Python27\Lib" folder.

Comment: Plz having a try to just "import urllib" in the interactive mode and let us know

Comment: it doesnt show anything after i typed in "import urllib"

Answer (score 0):

From a Python prompt:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> print urllib.__file__
```

Make sure the file is part of the Python distribution and not your own script.

Comment: Can you try ``from urllib import unwrap``?

Comment: i typed the following and it didnt show anything after that